# error (1, -2147483648) Cannot Play this Video

Tags: android, video, format, adt

I am trying to play an .mp4 video file, which I have added in a `raw` folder.
The result is that I always get an `error (1, -2147483648)`in LogCat.

After some research I notice this is caused by an unsupported codec/format. But the last 2 days I rendered the video in Adobe Premiere according to http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html? in ALL supportd formats and many more.The result is always the same: I get the error and a "Can't play this video." when the app launches.

My JAVA code is this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
       getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

       VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

       String fileName = "//BioLab/res/raw/sequence";

       vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(fileName));
       vv.start();

    }
}
```

And the main activity is this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<VideoView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/videoView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have seen games where they play fullscreen videos, like the company logo video. How do they do it? There  must be a universal way.

NOTE: I use in the java code the path  `"//BioLab/res/raw/sequence"` because if I use  `"/BioLab/res/raw/sequence.mp4"` or `“android.resource://” + getPackageName() +”/”+R.raw.video` I get another Error in

Logcat: `error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)`

Answer (score -1):

`error (1, -2147483648)` usually means that the link you feed your MediaPlayer( videoview in your case) is invalid or the file is corrupted.
The way you are trying to get the file from your RAW folder is fishy.
Trying the following.
I am assuming that the name of the file you are trying to play is sequence.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
       getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
       String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+ R.raw.sequence;
       Log.d("TAG", path);

       Uri url=Uri.parse(path);

       vv.setVideoURI(url);
       vv.start();
       vv.requestFocus();

    }
}
```

Comment: I I provide the path like this, not only it doesn't fix the error, but it adds another one: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: What is the name of the file you trying to play? Did you create the raw folder? Does the file sequence.mp4 or sequence.3gp exists in your raw folder?

Comment: The file is called sequence.mp4. Yes I have the raw folder and inside my file.

Comment: Hmmm! I have an application which use the same lines and it is working using videoview to play a mp4 video. Another question: is the raw folder located under res folder? Is raw lower case?

Comment: Yes it is inside the res folder and it is lower case exactly as seen in the code. Thank for your interest, helping me.

Comment: I found the problem, I was trying running an HD video on a physical device that is not supported. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: Glad you have figured it out! In that case we classify the stream as invalid.

Comment: And thanks for letting know. I was wondering what was the problem, since the code should definitely work. @user2186852